# List index out of range?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite

```
def print_db():
    con = lite.connect('master.db')
    print ('Enter a first name:')
    firstname = input('> ')
    with con:
        cur = con.cursor()
        data = cur.fetchone()
        cur.execute("SELECT * FROM Contacts WHERE First = (?);", (firstname,))
        list_title = ['First Name', 'Last Name', 'Phone', 'Email']
        k = 0
        for i in cur:
            print ("\n")
            for j in i:
                print (list_title[k],)
                print (j)
                if k < 5: k+=1
                else:
                    k = 0

    print (data)
    print ('Enter 1 to return to main menu')
    userinput = input('> ')
    if userinput == "1":
        main()
    else:
        main()
```

> traceback list index out of range at print (list_title)[k],)

Ok updated so you can see the whole function.

Comment: `k += 1 ; k %= len(list_title)`

Comment: Nothing to do with your error - but what's with the pointless sub-query? Just use `WHERE First = ?`

Comment: Haha yea that was another booboo, It was left over from something i was working on before.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`k < 5` will still be true until k reaches `5`, which means the maximum number of `k` is `4`.  Remember, list indices start counting from `0`, so the highest index for `k` is `3`.

So, when you try to get`list_title[4]`, you'll get an `IndexError`.

You'll have to change `k < 5` to `k < 4`.

```
for j in i:
            print (j)
            if k < 4: 
                print (list_title[k],) #Move it to the condition here
                k+=1
            else:
                k = 0
```

This way, when the value of `k` is `4`, `k` will be reset to `0`, and the error will never happen.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Still getting index out of range. But i did add more code above in my first post.

Comment: That fixed the out of range error but my list still doesn't display correctly in the console.

Comment: What is it displaying, and what are you expecting? Make sure the `print` statement is inside the condition.

Comment: It looks like this http://pastebin.com/QxqK0nMu and it doesn't even display the "Email:" title of the index :(

Comment: Nevermind i just did print (list_title[k], j) Now it looks right.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than manually incrementing an index, use [enumerate()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate)

```
for k, j in enumerate(i):
    print (list_title[k],)
    print (j)
```

or better, use [zip()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip)

```
for k, j in zip(list_title, i):
    print (k, j)
```

Here's a great presentation on looping in Python: http://nedbatchelder.com/text/iter.html

Comment: Thanks for the link, I will look into it Aron, The main thing that's been giving me trouble are these for loops, It's madness!